# How do I make grep results colored?

Tags: grep, color

I have some output of my program:
`# php check.php | grep -E "rule_1|rule_4"`

I would like results equaling to rule_1 to be red and results equaling to rule_4 to be blue.

Is this possible, because at this moment, everything is colored red.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alias egrep="grep -E --color=never"

alias egrep-grey="   GREP_COLOR='1;30' grep -E --color=always"
alias egrep-red="    GREP_COLOR='1;31' grep -E --color=always"
alias egrep-green="  GREP_COLOR='1;32' grep -E --color=always"
alias egrep-yellow=" GREP_COLOR='1;33' grep -E --color=always"
alias egrep-blue="   GREP_COLOR='1;34' grep -E --color=always"
alias egrep-magenta="GREP_COLOR='1;35' grep -E --color=always"
alias egrep-cyan="   GREP_COLOR='1;36' grep -E --color=always"
alias egrep-white="  GREP_COLOR='1;37' grep -E --color=always"

php check.php | egrep "rule_1|rule_4" | egrep-red "rule_1|$" | egrep-blue "rule_4|$"
```

Comment: Hello and welcome on serverfault. Please take a look at this: https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `grep` itself as a generic colorizing tool.  Something like [colortail](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/colortail.1.html) may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regex parser like [flex](http://flex.sourceforge.net/). But keep in mind that some patterns can be interpreted in unintuitive ways (e.g. if your parser is matching the longest pattern vs the shortest). For example the pattern `..1|aaa1` and the input `aaaa1` will usually match `..1`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [colorize.pl](http://freecode.com/projects/colorize_perl), which will print different colors for user-defined strings.

Here is a description from the colorize.pl project:

> Colorize.pl is a short script that reads from stdin and writes to stdout. Rows that match a user's search strings will be colorized with user-defined colors. Command line options are available. Colorization is done via ANSI escape codes.

On my Apple MacBook Pro, the following will print 'login' in read, and 'apple' in green:

```
tail /var/log/system.log | colorize.pl +:login +:apple
```